# Flutter local notification - switch from V9 to V14 of the library

Tags: flutter, flutter-local-notification

As I am updating the library used for notification, I am facing issue to make it work with payload. I have looked at the info about the library, but I did not understood what I must change to get it work again with the payload. For the rest it is fine.

below is the previous code

```
  const InitializationSettings initializationSettings =
    InitializationSettings(
      iOS: initializationSettingsIOS,
      android:initializationSettingsAndroid,
    );
    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(
        initializationSettings,
        onSelectNotification: selectNotification);
```

```
Future<void> selectNotification(String? payload) async {

    List<String> payloadParts = payload!.split(':');
    String viewName = payloadParts[0];
    String currentPayload = payloadParts[1];

    if (viewName == 'task') {

    Model_Tasks? singleDocument = await Model_Tasks.readOneDocument(currentPayload);

    if (singleDocument != null) {
      Get.to(() => Payload_V5(
        payload: currentPayload,
        page: tNotification,
        myDocument: Model_Tasks(
          id: payload,
          name: singleDocument.name,
          status: singleDocument.status,
          context: singleDocument.context,
          project_Name: singleDocument.project_Name,
          parent_Project_ID: singleDocument.parent_Project_ID,
          notes: singleDocument.notes,
          delegated_To: singleDocument.delegated_To,
          start_Date: singleDocument.start_Date,
          due_Date: singleDocument.due_Date,
          time_Needed: singleDocument.time_Needed,
          energy_Needed: singleDocument.energy_Needed,
          important: singleDocument.important,
          urgent: singleDocument.urgent,
          attachments: singleDocument.attachments,
          done: singleDocument.done,
        ),
      ),
      );
    } else {
      //TODO replace print par une vue avec Erreur
      print(tNoDocumentNotificationError);
    }
  }
    else if (viewName == 'project') {

      ProjectsModel? singleDocument = await ProjectsModel.readOneDocument(currentPayload);

      if (singleDocument != null) {
        Get.to(() => Notification_Project_Page(
          payload: currentPayload,
          project: ProjectsModel(
            id: payload,
            name: singleDocument.name,
            status: singleDocument.status,
            focus: singleDocument.focus,
            focus_ID: singleDocument.focus_ID,
            start_Date: singleDocument.start_Date,
            due_Date: singleDocument.due_Date,
            important: singleDocument.important,
            urgent: singleDocument.urgent,
            notes: singleDocument.notes,
            attachments: singleDocument.attachments,

          ),
        ),
        );
      } else {
        //TODO replace print par une vue avec Erreur
        print(tNoDocumentNotificationError);
      }

    }
}
```

```
static Future recordNotification (DateTime dateNotification, String recordID, String dataNotification, String mySource) async {

    int notificationId = NotificationApi.convertStringToHash(recordID);

    String fullPayload = '$mySource:$recordID';

    NotificationApi.showScheduledNotification(
      id: notificationId,
      title: dataNotification,
      body: 'Now:$dataNotification',
      payload: fullPayload,
      scheduledDate: dateNotification,
    );
  }
```

With the new library version, I have updated my code, but I do not find how to keep the payload like it was before. If you can help it would be appreciated. Thank you.

```
FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin = FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

  static final currentNotifications = FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

  Future<void> initializeNotification(BuildContext context) async {

    const AndroidInitializationSettings initializationSettingsAndroid = AndroidInitializationSettings("appicon");

    final DarwinInitializationSettings initializationSettingsIOS = DarwinInitializationSettings(
      requestSoundPermission: false,
      requestBadgePermission: false,
      requestAlertPermission: false,
      onDidReceiveLocalNotification: (id, title, body, payload) async {
        _displayNotificationDialog(context, title, body);
      },
    );

    final InitializationSettings initializationSettings = InitializationSettings(
      android:  initializationSettingsAndroid,
      iOS:      initializationSettingsIOS,
    );


    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(
      initializationSettings,
     // onDidReceiveNotificationResponse: onSelectNotification,
     //   onDidReceiveBackgroundNotificationResponse:    onSelectNotification);
 //   }
    );}
```

```
void onSelectNotification(NotificationResponse notificationResponse, String? payload) async {

  List<String> payloadParts = payload!.split(':');
  String viewName = payloadParts[0];
  String currentPayload = payloadParts[1];
     if (viewName == 'task') {

      Model_Tasks? singleDocument = await Model_Tasks.readOneDocument(currentPayload);

      if (singleDocument != null) {
        Get.to(() => Payload_V5(
          payload: currentPayload,
          page: tNotification,
          myDocument: Model_Tasks(
            id: payload,
            name: singleDocument.name,
            status: singleDocument.status,
            context: singleDocument.context,
            project_Name: singleDocument.project_Name,
            parent_Project_ID: singleDocument.parent_Project_ID,
            notes: singleDocument.notes,
            delegated_To: singleDocument.delegated_To,
            start_Date: singleDocument.start_Date,
            due_Date: singleDocument.due_Date,
            time_Needed: singleDocument.time_Needed,
            energy_Needed: singleDocument.energy_Needed,
            important: singleDocument.important,
            urgent: singleDocument.urgent,
            attachments: singleDocument.attachments,
            done: singleDocument.done,
          ),
        ),
        );
      } else {
        //TODO replace print par une vue avec Erreur
        print(tNoDocumentNotificationError);
      }
    }
    else if (viewName == 'project') {

      ProjectsModel? singleDocument = await ProjectsModel.readOneDocument(currentPayload);

      if (singleDocument != null) {
        Get.to(() => Notification_Project_Page(
          payload: currentPayload,
          project: ProjectsModel(
            id: payload,
            name: singleDocument.name,
            status: singleDocument.status,
            focus: singleDocument.focus,
            focus_ID: singleDocument.focus_ID,
            start_Date: singleDocument.start_Date,
            due_Date: singleDocument.due_Date,
            important: singleDocument.important,
            urgent: singleDocument.urgent,
            notes: singleDocument.notes,
            attachments: singleDocument.attachments,

          ),
        ),
        );
      } else {
        //TODO replace print par une vue avec Erreur
        print(tNoDocumentNotificationError);
      }
    }
}
```

```
 Future<void> selectNotification(String? payload) async {

    List<String> payloadParts = payload!.split(':');
    String viewName = payloadParts[0];
    String currentPayload = payloadParts[1];

    if (viewName == 'task') {

      Model_Tasks? singleDocument = await Model_Tasks.readOneDocument(currentPayload);

      if (singleDocument != null) {
        Get.to(() => Payload_V5(
          payload: currentPayload,
          page: tNotification,
          myDocument: Model_Tasks(
            id: payload,
            name: singleDocument.name,
            status: singleDocument.status,
            context: singleDocument.context,
            project_Name: singleDocument.project_Name,
            parent_Project_ID: singleDocument.parent_Project_ID,
            notes: singleDocument.notes,
            delegated_To: singleDocument.delegated_To,
            start_Date: singleDocument.start_Date,
            due_Date: singleDocument.due_Date,
            time_Needed: singleDocument.time_Needed,
            energy_Needed: singleDocument.energy_Needed,
            important: singleDocument.important,
            urgent: singleDocument.urgent,
            attachments: singleDocument.attachments,
            done: singleDocument.done,
          ),
        ),
        );
      } else {
        //TODO replace print par une vue avec Erreur
        print(tNoDocumentNotificationError);
      }
    }
    else if (viewName == 'project') {

      ProjectsModel? singleDocument = await ProjectsModel.readOneDocument(currentPayload);

      if (singleDocument != null) {
        Get.to(() => Notification_Project_Page(
          payload: currentPayload,
          project: ProjectsModel(
            id: payload,
            name: singleDocument.name,
            status: singleDocument.status,
            focus: singleDocument.focus,
            focus_ID: singleDocument.focus_ID,
            start_Date: singleDocument.start_Date,
            due_Date: singleDocument.due_Date,
            important: singleDocument.important,
            urgent: singleDocument.urgent,
            notes: singleDocument.notes,
            attachments: singleDocument.attachments,

          ),
        ),
        );
      } else {
        //TODO replace print par une vue avec Erreur
        print(tNoDocumentNotificationError);
      }

    }
  }
```